# How to create database

Tags: php

I'm a complete beginner in database thing &  I've been following lots of tutorial online on 'how to create database' but I don't seems to understand any. In most of the tutorial I see authors writing program like

```
Create database 'db_test'; 

Create table 'db_test';

User_I'd int (5) not null User_name varcher (25) not null
```

etc and asking us to copy past the code into phpmyadmin to create database & table.
Of course I know how to open phpmyadmin by typing localhost/phpmyadmin but I don't seems to see any place where I can copy past those codes. Or is it okay that I copy past the code in notpad and run the program?
Please give me ideas or guide on how I can implement those codes. I am using xampp server, notpad ++ & I have knowledge on CSS, php &HTML.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin there is a tab called "SQL".  Just click that and you will see a text box where you can paste your SQL and execute it.

Note however that your SQL above is invalid and will produce an error.  Heres a corrected version:

```
Create database `db_test`; 

Create table `db_test`
(
    `User_Id` int(5) not null,
    `User_name` varchar(25) not null
);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying in time. It helps a lot. By the way, in HTML Php we have opening & closing tag like <HTML> value </HTML> <?php value ?> etc.. What about in mysql?? Is their any?

Comment: No, there is nothing as only SQL can be included in an SQL script.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I've learned a lot. I hope to get more help in future.